# Joining 3 tables with subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery

I have this query:

```
select  IDPersonne, NumeroClientAXA, COUNT(1) as 'NbrDoublons'
from PortefeuillePersonne
group by IDPersonne, NumeroClientAXA
having COUNT(1)>1
```

I want to join 3 tables with this subquery on
I tried something like that:

```
select prs.NumeroSocietaire, 
pp.NumeroClientAXA, pp.IDPortefeuille,  pf.Code, pf.Intitule, count(1)
 from PortefeuillePersonne pp
    Join Portefeuille pf
        ON pf.IDPortefeuille = pp.IDPortefeuille
    Join Personne prs
        ON prs.IDPersonne IN (select  IDPersonne
                             from PortefeuillePersonne
                             group by IDPersonne
                             having  COUNT(IDPersonne)>1)
```

it keeps telling me: 
Column 'Personne.NumeroSocietaire' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

can you help me, please?

Comment: You can't mix aggregates with non-aggregates, so either `GROUP BY` all the columns in your query, or change `COUNT(1)` to `1`?

Comment: Second query, you;re using an Aggregate function `COUNT` without a `Group By`

Comment: the problem is that I want tp retrieve records with the same IDPersonne and NumClientAxxa

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want records that have more than one `PortefeuillePersonne` record, you should change it to something like this:

```
select prs.NumeroSocietaire, pp.NumeroClientAXA, pp.IDPortefeuille,  pf.Code,
    pf.Intitule, count(pp.IDPersonne)
from PortefeuillePersonne pp
    Join Portefeuille pf
        ON pf.IDPortefeuille = pp.IDPortefeuille
    Join Personne prs
        ON prs.IDPersonne = pp.IDPersonne
group by prs.NumeroSocietaire, pp.NumeroClientAXA, pp.IDPortefeuille,  pf.Code,
    pf.Intitule
having  COUNT(pp.IDPersonne)>1
```

Any fields that are in the `select` list must either be aggregated or be included in the `group by` in SQL Server.

Comment: I want to retrieve records that have the same IDPersonne and NumClientAxa

Answer (score 0):

```
Select    prs.NumeroSocietaire
        , pp.NumeroClientAXA
        , pp.IDPortefeuille
        , pf.Code
        , pf.Intitule
        , count(1)
from        PortefeuillePersonne pp
Inner Join (    select      IDPersonne
                from        PortefeuillePersonne
                group by    IDPersonne
                having      COUNT(IDPersonne)>1
            ) p1            ON pp.IDPersonne = P1.IDPersonne
Inner Join Portefeuille pf  ON pf.IDPortefeuille = pp.IDPortefeuille
Inner Join Personne prs     ON prs.IDPersonne = pp.IDPersonne
GROUP BY  prs.NumeroSocietaire
        , pp.NumeroClientAXA
        , pp.IDPortefeuille
        , pf.Code
        , pf.Intitule
```

Comment: This can work but I need to retrieve records with the same IDPersonne and NumClientAxa

Answer (score 0):

It is not a valid `join` attempt;

```
ON prs.IDPersonne IN (select  IDPersonne
                     from PortefeuillePersonne
                     group by IDPersonne
                     having  COUNT(IDPersonne)>1)
```

You should join the subselect as a set, so complete query should looks like;

```
select prs.NumeroSocietaire, pp.NumeroClientAXA, pp.IDPortefeuille,  pf.Code, pf.Intitule, count(1) 
from PortefeuillePersonne pp
join Portefeuille pf ON pf.IDPortefeuille = pp.IDPortefeuille
join (select IDPersonne
             from PortefeuillePersonne
             group by IDPersonne
             having  COUNT(IDPersonne)>1) A ON A.IDPersonne = prs.IDPersonne
group by prs.NumeroSocietaire, pp.NumeroClientAXA, pp.IDPortefeuille,  pf.Code, pf.Intitule
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    first_name, last_name, salary
FROM
    employees join salaries on employees.emp_no = salaries.emp_no
WHERE
    employees.emp_no IN (SELECT 
            emp_no
        FROM
            dept_manager)
            group by employees.emp_no
            order by employees.emp_no;
```